# Suppose that f(x) and g(x) are irreducible over F and that deg f(x) and deg g(x) are relatively prime. Show g(x) is irreducible over F(a)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

"Suppose that f(x) and g(x) are irreducible over F and that deg f(x) and deg g(x) are relatively prime. Suppose $a$ is a zero of f(x) in some extension field of F. Show that g(x) is irreducible over F(a)."

This is from Gallian's *Abstract Algebra* textbook. The one problem I have so far is how do we know $a$ is also not a zero of g(x)? The problem does not assume that $a$ is only just a zero of f(x) but not g(x). If it is a zero of g(x), then it has a linear factor over F(a) and it is reducible.

Another point: most of the answers to this problem starts with "Let b be a root of g(x) in some extension field of F(a)"...
But doesn't that already assume that that g(x) cannot be reducible over F(a) which is what we are trying to prove?
Why not say "Let b be a root of g(x) in some extension field of F(a) and b is not a root of f(x)"
Because that way, we eliminate the possibility that F(a,b)=F(a).

Comment: Given a field $K$ and a polynomial $g(x)$ with coefficients in $K$, there is always an extension of $K$ that contains a root of $g(x)$. This is a basic fact of field extensions. So there is absolutely no problem in considering *some* extension of $F(a)$ where there is a root for $g(x)$, since $g(x)$ has coefficients in $F$ and hence can be considered to have coefficient sin $F(a)$. Note that there is no assumption that the extension is *nontrivial*. It doesn't assert it is $F(a)$ itself, but also does not assert it isn't.

Comment: As to why no root of $g(x)$ can be a root of $f(x)$: since both are irreducible over $F$, they would both be **the** irreducible polynomial for the root over $F$, up to a constant. But they have different degrees, so that is *a priori* utterly impossible.

Comment: same question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897035/suppose-that-fx-and-gx-are-irreducible-over-f-and-that-deg-fx-and?rq=1

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh ok. So what you're saying is that if a was a root of both g and f, then they are both the minimal polynomial (after multiplying by a constant so the leading term is 1) and that would imply one would divide the other, but that would imply the polynomial with the larger degree would be reducible hence a contradiction.

Comment: @William: They would both be the irreducible, hence they would have the same degree (no larger or smaller). But if they have relatively prime order, the only way they could have the same degree is if their degree is $1$. But polynomials of degree $1$ are *always* irreducible, so there is nothing to prove in that case and you are really working in the case where their degrees are greater than $1$.